# Npm install "error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’"

Tags: python, node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, npm-install

Transitioning over to Buster from Stretch and trying to rebuild our node application.  Running Raspberry Pi CM3L

OS Buster 5.10.103-v7+ (was Stretch 4.9.59-v7+)
node-gyp 9.0.0 (was 3.6.2)
node 16.15.0 (was 8.9.4)
npm 8.5.5 (was 6.0.0)
Python 3.7.3 (was Python 2)
I upgraded NaN to the latest package that support Node 16.6.1

Terminal output after running npm install.

```
> comm@0.0.0 install
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
gyp info using node@16.15.0 | linux | arm
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/devel/S/SystemServices/ControllerJs/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/pi/devel/S/SystemServices/ControllerJs',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/pi/devel/S/SystemServices/ControllerJs/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/comm/comm.o
<command-line>: warning: "V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" redefined
<command-line>: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from ../comm.cc:7:
../Messages.h:322:1: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration
 typedef enum {
 ^~~~~~~
../comm.cc: In member function ‘virtual void GpioInterruptWorker::HandleOKCallback()’:
../comm.cc:112:29: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    callback->Call(argc, argv);
                             ^
In file included from ../comm.cc:4:
../../../node_modules/nan/nan.h:1744:3: note: declared here
   Call(int argc, v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[]) const {
   ^~~~
../comm.cc: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE InitializeHardware(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
../comm.cc:123:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Value::Int32Value()’
    unsigned int bootMode = info[0]->Int32Value();
                                                ^
In file included from /home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/node.h:63,
                 from ../comm.cc:3:
/home/pi/.cache/node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/v8.h:3107:40: note: candidate: ‘v8::Maybe<int> v8::Value::Int32Value(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’
   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<int32_t> Int32Value(Local<Context> context) const;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You updated from Node 8 to Node 16: those are _wildly_ different versions, and you'll want to read through every set of release notes for Node 9, through 16 to see what got changed that requires updating  your code over. Start at https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V9.md#9.0.0 and work your way up. Having said that, presumably that "comm" is [https://www.npmjs.com/package/comm], and if you're going to compile it, its compile target needs to match your Node version. It's 8 years old, so I _very much_ doubt it can compile for modern Node at all.

Comment: Okay, thank you for providing a solid starting point.  I was hoping the compiler would point to specific things that could be addressed but I will start reading up the change log.

Comment: I highly suspect you'll want to find a modern alternative to `comm`, given how long it's been since it got updated =(

Comment: The comm file is our custom c++ code.  We'll need to rewrite it entirely.

Comment: Ahhhh yeah if it's your own code then you'll definitely need to rewrite some of it to use the more recent V8 interfaces.